# Does Mirror Ball double/triple Magic Missile damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Mirror Ball source has a special attribute *"Magic Missile fires [1-2] extra missiles"*. If I'm using a one missile rune (e.g. Glacial Spike), does this effectively double/triple the DPS of Magic Missile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you roll a 2 extra missle then your tripling it,

because you're shooting your one missle.... so thats 1x.. and 2 more.. so 2x... then 3x.

if you roll 1 extra missle then your doubling

Comment: there is one caveat.  the extra missiles do not proc.  so no arcane power in crit or loh ect

Comment: What about the "split" rune? Do you shoot 9 missiles with a +2 mirror ball?

Comment: I believe it would be 5 missiles. It's a bit of a waste to use it with Split either way, you're reducing the damage per shot by a lot.